# Safari freezing on Mac

Tags: macos, safari

Safari is timing out or freezing after I go to one or two websites. Why?

I’ve tried:

- Deleting all Cookies
- Clearing my History

Comment: macOS version?  Safari version?  Does the same thing happen in other browsers?  Does it happen in a Private window?  Do you have any plugins installed?

Answer (score 1):

## Updating your Software

Make sure you are on the latest software. Go to  Apple menu > App Store > Updates and install any version of MacOS X and/or Safari that are available.

## Clearing Safari caches

You can clear Safari caches manually:

1. Reboot your Mac into Safe Mode:

> Start or restart your Mac, then immediately press and hold the Shift key. The Apple logo appears on your display.
>
> Release the Shift key when you see
> the login window. If your startup disk
> is encrypted with FileVault, you might
> be asked to log in twice: once to
> unlock the startup disk, and again to
> log in to the Finder.

https://support.apple.com/HT201262

2. From Finder press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and enter the following path:

   `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/`
3. Remove Safari caches by placing them in the trash
4. Restart the Mac normally
5. Open Safari

<sup>Content re-worded from http://osxdaily.com/2015/01/18/troubleshoot-safari-freezes-crashes-mac-os-x/</sup>

Comment: Your directions to start in **safe mode** are lacking according to **Start up in safe mode** in **Apple's** documentation: https://support.apple.com/HT201262

Comment: This answer seems oddly familiar:  http://osxdaily.com/2015/01/18/troubleshoot-safari-freezes-crashes-mac-os-x/

Comment: What does „If you don't see the Apple logo, learn what to do.“ mean?

Comment: Why does one need to boot into safe mode for this? Isn‘t it enough to quit Safari and delete the cache?

Comment: @nohillside, The "learn what to do" part was supposed to be a hyperlink as in "If you don't see the Apple logo, [learn what to do](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204267)." and had he properly quoted the content of the Apple document correctly in the first place, it probably would not have been an issue.